# Having some trouble finishing Sales Tracking program in Java

Tags: java

SO I am working on an assignment and I get it most of the way done. Unfortunately, implementing the final method has been unsuccessful. I'm not sure if I am just not initializing the variables correctly or what. If I test each of the other methods individually then it will display exactly what I need it to but getting the displaySalesInfo method to work seems to be beyond me. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
public class SalesTracking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declare arrays
        String[] monthArray = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        double[] monthlySales = new double[12];

        int highestMonth = computeHighestMonth(monthlySales), lowestMonth = computeLowestMonth(monthlySales);
        double totalSales = computeTotalSales(monthlySales), averageSales = computeAverageSales(monthlySales), highestSales = monthlySales[highestMonth], lowestSales = monthlySales[lowestMonth];           




        //call methods
        getSales(monthArray, monthlySales);
        //computeTotalSales(monthlySales);
        //computeAverageSales(monthlySales);
        //computeHighestMonth(monthlySales);
        //computeLowestMonth(monthlySales);
        displaySalesInfo(totalSales, averageSales, highestMonth, highestSales, lowestMonth, lowestSales);

    } //end main

    public static void getSales(String monthArray[], double monthlySales[]) {

        //prepare for input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //input sales
        for(int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) {

            //System.out.print("Enter sales for " + monthArray[i] + ": ");
            monthlySales[i] = input.nextDouble();

        } //end for

    } //end getSales

    public static double computeTotalSales(double monthlySales[]) {

        double totalSales = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) {

            totalSales += monthlySales[i];

        } //end for

        //System.out.println("Yearly Total: " + totalSales);
        return totalSales;

    } //end computeTotalSales

    public static double computeAverageSales(double monthlySales[]) {

        double total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) {

            total += monthlySales[i];

        } //end for

        double averageSales = total / monthlySales.length;

        //System.out.println("Average Sales: " + averageSales);
        return averageSales;

    } //end computeAverageSales

    public static int computeHighestMonth(double monthlySales[]) {

        int highestMonth = 0;
        double highestSales = monthlySales[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) {

            double maxNumber = monthlySales[i];

            if(maxNumber > monthlySales[highestMonth]) {

                highestMonth = i;

            } //end if

            if(highestSales < monthlySales[i]) {

                highestSales = monthlySales[i];

            } //end if

        } //end for

        //System.out.println("The highest month is: " + highestMonth);
        //System.out.println("The highest sales amount was: " + highestSales);
        return highestMonth;

    } //end computeHighestMonth

    public static int computeLowestMonth(double monthlySales[]) {

        int lowestMonth = 11;
        double lowestSales = monthlySales[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) {

            double minNumber = monthlySales[i];

            if(minNumber < monthlySales[lowestMonth]) {

                lowestMonth = i;

            } //end if

            if(lowestSales > monthlySales[i]) {

                lowestSales = monthlySales[i];

            } //end if

        } //end for

        //System.out.println("The lowest month is: " + lowestMonth);
        //System.out.println("The lowest sales amount was: " + lowestSales);
        return lowestMonth;

    } //end computeLowestMonth

    public static void displaySalesInfo(double totalSales, double averageSales, int highestMonth, double highestSales, int lowestMonth, double lowestSales) {

        System.out.println("Yearly Total: " + totalSales);
        System.out.println("Average Sales: " + averageSales);
        System.out.println("The highest month is: " + highestMonth);
        System.out.println("The highest sales amount was: " + highestSales);
        System.out.println("The lowest month is: " + lowestMonth);
        System.out.println("The lowest sales amount was: " + lowestSales);

    } //end displaySaleInfo

} //end class
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. Is there any errors? What is happening? Post a [mcve]

Comment: You should put the error log to help others to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should have to call `getSales(monthArray, monthlySales);` before calculate other figures.

```
 getSales(monthArray, monthlySales); // call this before otheres
 int highestMonth = computeHighestMonth(monthlySales), lowestMonth = computeLowestMonth(monthlySales);
 double totalSales = computeTotalSales(monthlySales), averageSales = computeAverageSales(monthlySales), highestSales = monthlySales[highestMonth], lowestSales = monthlySales[lowestMonth];
```

Your programming technique is very bad. Less readability. I recommend the following code.

```
// declare arrays
String[] monthArray = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December" };
double[] monthlySales = new double[12];
getSales(monthArray, monthlySales);
int highestMonth = computeHighestMonth(monthlySales);
int lowestMonth = computeLowestMonth(monthlySales);
double totalSales = computeTotalSales(monthlySales);
double averageSales = computeAverageSales(monthlySales);
double highestSales = monthlySales[highestMonth];
double lowestSales = monthlySales[lowestMonth];
```

Comment: Wow! Very bad seems a bit harsh. I am still a bit new to this and this is my first post on this site. However, I do appreciate your help and I will take your readability suggestions into consideration. Thank you.

Comment: @Karlnage take with grain of salt--we are all just anonymous internet names anyways.